# ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dependencies, react-dom, testing-library

I have this problem, I want to run or build a project in React, it is in version 16.4.2, but when I want to do what is done at the beginning, that is, npm install, I already have errors that I don't really know how to solve, if I Can you please come up with something, I would appreciate it.

Thank you so much.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.28",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.0.0-alpha-5",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-select": "^4.0.2",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.14.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-select": "^4.0.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App].",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reducer from './store/index';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
    }
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers())

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.scss';
import Routers from './routers/';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <Routers/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\NB-RMORALES\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NB-RMORALES\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-23T22_44_28_352Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried to install each of the dependencies manually but it's one after the other, so you can't do it like that.

I tried this, npm install --legacy-peer-deps, but it didn't work either.

---

I don't know why the same thing always happens to npm, when there is a need to modify a project that has been going on for some time, and you want to make new modifications to that project, the libraries always have problems. :/....... why?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most relevant lines of that stacktrace are here:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.4.2" from the root project
...
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
```

In your `package.json` you have conflicting dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.4.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
```

Your `react` and `react-dom` versions should match.

These may not be the only two, but you can continue to look for other dependency conflicts by fixing these two first and running `npm install` again to see if any more errors appear.

Comment: Thanks friend, it helped me, I began to unravel each one of the dressing conflicts, but I got to one that can't be unraveled anymore. Thank you anyway.